# Get the first free column in a Google Sheet via PHP API

Tags: php, laravel-5, google-sheets-api, google-api-php-client

I'm using the Google Sheets API to write some data into the sheets, but so far either I clear it all and write everything again or I write in new rows (which Sheets API does by default).

I am now writing a single column per run, but I need to get the first available column in the sheet, so I can pass it as the range of writing.

This is my code so far:

```
        $sheet = new \Google_Service_Sheets($this->client);
        $range = "'" . $sheetName . "'!" . $rangeArg . (strlen($rangeArg) == 2 ? '' : count($data) + 1000);

        $response = $sheet->spreadsheets_values->get($this->sheetId, $range);

        if (!$clear && $response && $response->values) {
            $c = count($response->values);
            $newRange = (intval(substr($rangeArg, 1, 1)) + $c);
            $newRange = substr($rangeArg, 0, 1) . $newRange . substr($rangeArg, 2);
            $range = "'" . $sheetName . "'!" . $newRange . (count($data) + 1000);
        }

        $options = ['valueInputOption' => 'RAW'];

        if ($clear) {
            $sheet->spreadsheets_values->clear($this->sheetId, $range, new \Google_Service_Sheets_ClearValuesRequest);
        }

       $body = new \Google_Service_Sheets_ValueRange(['values' => $data, 'majorDimension' => $columns ? 'COLUMNS' : 'ROWS']);
       $ok = $sheet->spreadsheets_values->append($this->sheetId, $range, $body, $options);
    }
```

I saw someone on the internet mentioning `getLastColumn()` as a function, but it's not available in my version of sheets API apparently or it's just not in this package.

```
google/apiclient                   v2.5.0
google/apiclient-services          v0.138
google/auth                        v1.9.0
```

Answer (score 1):

[getLastColumn](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet) is an appscript method.    Something like that is not available with the php client library is only going to give you [google sheets api](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest) methods,

The only way to find out whats on the sheet is to buffer it and scan though as you are already doing.   Unfortunately with PHP there is really no easy way of doing it.

```
$response = $service->spreadsheets_values->batchGet($spreadsheetId);
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont use PHP, but I am 100% sure, that in Google API its closest things on PHP and Python, just syntax of languages would be different

So for get the first free column through Google Sheet API (using Python):

```
import httplib2
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

DOCUMENT_ID = '1ma8DG3IQJ377900iaFUPu9qXoThuP22buLgEILVfO1M'


def get_service_sacc():
    creds_json = 'param-param-1344-fae81984f8a8.json'
    scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']

    creds_service = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(creds_json, scopes).authorize(httplib2.Http())
    return build('sheets', 'v4', http=creds_service)


sheet_values = get_service_sacc().spreadsheets().values()

_range = "A1:A9"
# or use _range = "Name of List!A1:A9", if u want to take info not from first list of sheets.
write = sheet_values.append(spreadsheetId=DOCUMENT_ID, range=_range, valueInputOption="USER_ENTERED",body={}).execute()
```

deal_id = str(write['updates']['updatedRange']).split('!')

little info about how get creds.json, if you wanna make thru this method (its from Service Account (https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts), create it, go to you Cloud Developer Console, create a some project, create service account, append it to project, and also after creation, click on three dots at actions (in account line), click Manage keys -> Add key -> Create new key -> json and end it, than download that json, and put it together in one directory of you project where u start you language logic.)

info about, how append works (https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append)